# Telerik reporting with ASP.NET MVC: report viewer is not correctly rendered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, telerik, asp.net-web-api2

**Problem description**

ASP.NET MVC Telerik report viewer is not rendered. The HTML code which is generated in the page is an empty div.

```
<div id="reportViewer1">

</div>
```

And thanks to break points and google chrome developers tool (network tab) I know that the report REST service (which is created by default at the path /api/report) is never called. I also know that the problem is not the REST service in itself (which is correctly configured in Global.asax), because I tried to navigate to /api/reports and the break point in the api controller was hitted, and it returns me the following result:

```
[{"name":"PDF","localizedName":"Acrobat (PDF) file"},{"name":"CSV","localizedName":"CSV (comma delimited)"},{"name":"XLS","localizedName":"Excel 97-2003"},{"name":"RTF","localizedName":"Rich Text Format"},{"name":"IMAGE","localizedName":"TIFF file"},{"name":"MHTML","localizedName":"Web Archive"},{"name":"XPS","localizedName":"XPS Document"}]
```

**Details**

I am new to Telerik reporting and I'm trying to show a report in a web page thanks to server-side wrapper of HTML5 report viewer.

This one to be clear: http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/mvc-report-viewer-extension-overview.html

I used the template that you can find under Add new item ---> Telerik Report Viewer Page Q2 2015 ---> Sample report definition

If you know the template, then you probably know that it prepares everything it's necessary to use Telerik report viewer (references to Telerik assemblies and so on) and folders containing all necessary files, including a sample report called SampleReport.trdx which is useful to test.

However, just after I added the template the following page came out

[image]

As you can see there are some warnings, and here below you can read the complete and detailed log of template creation. The important thing to read are the warnings: it seems that Telerik uses an older version of some .NET assemblies.

```
07/12/2015 10:38:51 Build Started
Check Framework Support
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Kendo.Mvc
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.CSharp
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Data
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Drawing
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Net.Http.Formatting
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.DynamicData
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.Entity
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.ApplicationServices
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Core
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Data.DataSetExtensions
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.Http
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.Http.WebHost
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Xml.Linq
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.Extensions
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.Abstractions
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.Routing
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Xml
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Configuration
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.Services
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.EnterpriseServices
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Net.Http
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Net.Http.WebRequest
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.Helpers
Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.Mvc
Assembly Version: 5.2.3.0
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.Optimization
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.Razor
Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.WebPages
Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : System.Web.WebPages.Razor
Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Telerik.Reporting
Assembly Version: 9.1.15.731
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi
Assembly Version: 9.1.15.731
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Telerik.Reporting.XpsRendering
Assembly Version: 9.1.15.731
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Telerik.ReportViewer.Mvc
Assembly Version: 9.1.15.731
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : WebGrease
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Antlr3.Runtime
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Newtonsoft.Json
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : EntityFramework
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : EntityFramework.SqlServer
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Owin
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.Owin
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.Owin.Security
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Assembly name is null: False
Assembly : Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount
Assembly Version: 
Product Version: 9.1.15.731
Verify Telerik Reporting Version: True
Build Completed
Cancel the form closing: False
Add project references
Get project references.
Reference already available: Telerik.ReportViewer.Mvc, Version=9.1.15.731, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be
Add required references.
Add project references
Get project references.
Reference already available: Telerik.Reporting, Version=9.1.15.731, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be
Reference already available: Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi, Culture=neutral, Version=9.1.15.731, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be
Reference already available: Telerik.Reporting.XpsRendering, Version=9.1.15.731, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be
Verify Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost package references
Is System.Web.Http.WebHost reference version compatible. Current: 4.0.0.0 | Required 4.0.0.0
Verify Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure package references
Is Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure reference version compatible. Current: 1.0.0.0 | Required 1.0.0.0
Verify Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core package references
Is System.Web.Http reference version compatible. Current: 4.0.0.0 | Required 4.0.0.0
Verify Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client package references
Is System.Net.Http.Formatting reference version compatible. Current: 4.0.0.0 | Required 4.0.0.0
Verify Microsoft.Net.Http package references
Is System.Net.Http reference version compatible. Current: 4.0.0.0 | Required 2.0.0.0
Warning: The referenced System.Net.Http assembly version is newer. You should add the following binding redirect:
      <dependentAssembly>
             <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" />
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      For more information see: Assembly Binding Redirection MSDN article
Is System.Net.Http.WebRequest reference version compatible. Current: 4.0.0.0 | Required 2.0.0.0
Warning: The referenced System.Net.Http.WebRequest assembly version is newer. You should add the following binding redirect:
      <dependentAssembly>
             <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.WebRequest" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" />
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      For more information see: Assembly Binding Redirection MSDN article
Verify Newtonsoft.Json package references
Is Newtonsoft.Json reference version compatible. Current: 6.0.0.0 | Required 4.5.0.0
Warning: The referenced Newtonsoft.Json assembly version is newer. You should add the following binding redirect:
      <dependentAssembly>
             <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      For more information see: Assembly Binding Redirection MSDN article
Enhance Global.asax: Global.asax.cs
Namespace Kind: vsCMElementNamespace
Class Kind: vsCMElementClass
Class Name MvcApplication
Class derives from System.Web.HttpApplication
Function Kind: vsCMElementFunction
Function name Application_Start
Function full name WebApplication3.MvcApplication.Application_Start
Namespace Kind: vsCMElementNamespace
Import System.Web.Http is available
'using System.Web.Http' statement is already available.
Namespace Kind: vsCMElementNamespace
Import Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi is available
'using Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi' statement is already available.
Register routes
Is REST Report Service route registered: True
Class with name ReportsController is found
Adding TelerikViewerPage.cshtml.Type project item
Adding TelerikViewerPage.cshtml.Trdx project item
Added prova.cshtml
Adding telerikReportViewer-9.1.15.731.min.js project item
Adding telerikReportViewer-9.1.15.731.css project item
Adding telerikReportViewerTemplate-9.1.15.731.html project item
Adding SampleReport.trdx project item
Added SampleReport.trdx
Adding ReportsController.cs project item
```

So, as the warnings indicate, I added the followings lines in my web.config file (inside the assemblyBinding section).

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.WebRequest" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

However, the report viewer is not correctly rendered: the HTML helper only creates and empty div

```
<div id="reportViewer1">

</div>
```

I can't understand what is the problem, and it would be nice if someone could give me a suggestion.

Here below you can see the code of my razor page which contains the definition of the report viewer (it's the default one, which is generated by the template)

```
@using WebApplication3.Views.Home
@using Telerik.ReportViewer.Mvc
@using Telerik.Reporting
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Telerik MVC HTML5 Report Viewer";
}

@section styles
{
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <style>
        #reportViewer1 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 5px;
            right: 5px;
            top: 5px;
            bottom: 5px;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: Verdana, Arial;
        }
    </style>

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/ReportViewer/styles/telerikReportViewer-9.1.15.731.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
}

@(Html.TelerikReporting().ReportViewer()
        // Each report viewer must have an id - it will be used by the initialization script
        // to find the element and initialize the report viewer.
        .Id("reportViewer1")
        // The URL of the service which will serve reports.
        // The URL corresponds to the name of the controller class (ReportsController).
        // For more information on how to configure the service please check http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/telerik-reporting-rest-conception.html.
        .ServiceUrl(Url.Content("~/api/reports/"))
        // The URL for the report viewer template. The template can be edited -
        // new functionalities can be added and unneeded ones can be removed.
        // For more information please check http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/html5-report-viewer-templates.html.
        .TemplateUrl(Url.Content("~/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-9.1.15.731.html"))
        // Strongly typed ReportSource - TypeReportSource or UriReportSource.
        .ReportSource(new UriReportSource() { Uri = "Reports/SampleReport.trdx" })
        // Specifies whether the viewer is in interactive or print preview mode.
        // PrintPreview - Displays the paginated report as if it is printed on paper. Interactivity is not enabled.
        // Interactive - Displays the report in its original width and height with no paging. Additionally interactivity is enabled.
        .ViewMode(ViewMode.Interactive)
        // Sets the scale mode of the viewer.
        // Three modes exist currently:
        // FitPage - The whole report will fit on the page (will zoom in or out), regardless of its width and height.
        // FitPageWidth - The report will be zoomed in or out so that the width of the screen and the width of the report match.
        // Specific - Uses the scale to zoom in and out the report.
        .ScaleMode(ScaleMode.Specific)
        // Zoom in and out the report using the scale
        // 1.0 is equal to 100%, i.e. the original size of the report
        .Scale(1.0)
        // Sets whether the viewer’s client session to be persisted between the page’s refreshes(ex. postback).
        // The session is stored in the browser’s sessionStorage and is available for the duration of the page session.
        .PersistSession(false)
        // Sets the print mode of the viewer.
        .PrintMode(PrintMode.AutoSelect)
        // Defers the script initialization statement. Check the scripts section below -
        // each deferred script will be rendered at the place of TelerikReporting().DeferredScripts().
        .Deferred()
        .ClientEvents(
                events => events
                    .RenderingBegin("onRenderingBegin")
                    .RenderingEnd("onRenderingEnd")
                    .PrintBegin("onPrintBegin")
                    .PrintEnd("onPrintEnd")
                    .ExportBegin("onExportBegin")
                    .ExportEnd("onExportBegin")
                    .UpdateUi("onUpdateUi")
                    .PageReady("onPageReady")
                    .Error("onError")
                    )
        // Uncomment the code below to see the custom parameter editors in action
        //.ParameterEditors(
        //        editors => editors
        //            .SingleSelectEditor("createSingleSelectEditor")
        //            .CustomEditors(new CustomParameterEditor
        //            {
        //                MatchFunction = "customMatch",
        //                CreateEditorFunction = "createCustomEditor"
        //            })
        //)
)

@section scripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/ReportViewer/js/telerikReportViewer-9.1.15.731.min.js")"></script>

    <!--kendo.all.min.js can be used as well instead of kendo.web.min.js and kendo.mobile.min.js-->
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    <!--kendo.mobile.min.js - optional, if gestures/touch support is required-->
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        function onRenderingBegin() {
            console.log("rendering begin!");
        }
        function onRenderingEnd() {
            console.log("rendering end!");
        }
        function onPrintBegin() {
            console.log("print begin!");
        }
        function onPrintEnd() {
            console.log("print end!");
        }
        function onExportBegin() {
            console.log("export begin!");
        }
        function onExportEnd() {
            console.log("export end!");
        }
        function onUpdateUi() {
            console.log("update ui!");
        }
        function onError() {
            console.log("error!");
        }
        function onPageReady() {
            console.log("page ready!");
        }

        function createSingleSelectEditor(placeholder, options) {
            var dropDownElement = $(placeholder).html('<div></div>');
            var parameter,
                  valueChangedCallback = options.parameterChanged,
                  dropDownList;

            function onChange() {
                var val = dropDownList.value();
                valueChangedCallback(parameter, val);
            }

            return {
                beginEdit: function (param) {

                    parameter = param;

                    $(dropDownElement).kendoDropDownList({
                        dataTextField: "name",
                        dataValueField: "value",
                        value: parameter.value,
                        dataSource: parameter.availableValues,
                        change: onChange
                    });

                    dropDownList = $(dropDownElement).data("kendoDropDownList");
                }
            };
        }

        function customMatch(parameter) {
            return Boolean(parameter.availableValues)
                && !parameter.multivalue
                && parameter.type === telerikReportViewer.ParameterTypes.BOOLEAN;
        }

        function createCustomEditor(placeholder, options) {
            var dropDownElement = $(placeholder).html('<div></div>');
            var parameter,
                  valueChangedCallback = options.parameterChanged,
                  dropDownList;

            function onChange() {
                var val = dropDownList.value();
                valueChangedCallback(parameter, val);
            }

            return {
                beginEdit: function (param) {

                    parameter = param;

                    $(dropDownElement).kendoDropDownList({
                        dataTextField: "name",
                        dataValueField: "value",
                        value: parameter.value,
                        dataSource: parameter.availableValues,
                        change: onChange
                    });

                    dropDownList = $(dropDownElement).data("kendoDropDownList");
                }
            };
        }
    </script>

    @(

        // All deferred initialization statements will be rendered here
        Html.TelerikReporting().DeferredScripts()
    )
}
```

Here below the code of the REST service

```
public class ReportsController : ReportsControllerBase
{
        static ReportServiceConfiguration configurationInstance;

        static ReportsController()
        {
            //This is the folder that contains the XML (trdx) report definitions
            //In this case this is the app folder
            var reportsPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");

            //Add resolver for trdx report definitions, 
            //then add resolver for class report definitions as fallback resolver; 
            //finally create the resolver and use it in the ReportServiceConfiguration instance.
            var resolver = new ReportFileResolver(reportsPath)
                .AddFallbackResolver(new ReportTypeResolver());

            //Setup the ReportServiceConfiguration
            configurationInstance = new ReportServiceConfiguration
            {
                HostAppId = "MvcApp",
                Storage = new FileStorage(),
                ReportResolver = resolver,
                // ReportSharingTimeout = 0,
                // ClientSessionTimeout = 15,
            };
        }

        public ReportsController()
        {
            //Initialize the service configuration
            this.ReportServiceConfiguration = configurationInstance;
        }
}
```

And here a print screen of the folders tree. Prova.cshtml is the file which contains the report viewer.

[image]

prova.cshtml is used in the index page

```
@Html.Partial("prova")
```

... and in the index page you find the empty div.

Comment: Did you work this out?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. At the end I simply used the HTML 5 report viewer, instead of the server-side wrapper.